# Mongodb MapReduce with 2 collections is giving duplicate key error in sharding

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections:

1. MasterDetails
2. Transactions.

I am using MapReduce to make one to many relationship here.
My code works fine for single instance but when I am running same code in sharding it is giving Error 'like Unable to insert duplicate key'.

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong ?

1) Here I am creating map for MasterDetails collection:

```
var mapMaster = function(){ var out = { PID:this.PID , LOCATIONS : this.LOCATIONS , STATUS : this.STATUS , COUNT :this.COUNT }; emit (this.CODE , out ); }
```

2) And this map is for Transactions collection:

```
var mapTrans = function(){ var out = {AMT : this.AMT , DATETIME : this.DATETIME , LNAME : this.LNAME , ACCTID :this.ACCTID };
emit(this.CODE , out); }
```

3) Now Reduce function:

```
 reduce = function (k, values) { 
var result = {} , 
commentFields = { "PID" : '', "AMT" :'', "DATETIME" : '', "LNAME" : '' , "ACCID" : ''}; 
values.forEach(function(value){ 
var field;if("PID" in value) { if(!("records" in result)){ result.records = []; } result.records.push(value); } else if ("records" in value){ if(!("records" in result)){ result.records = []; } 
result.records.push.apply(result.records, value.records); } 
for (field in value) { if (value.hasOwnProperty(field) && !(field in commentFields)){ result[field] = value[field]; } } }); return result; }
```

Now time for applying MapReduce on collection-

```
db.test_collection.mapReduce(mapTrans , reduce , {out: {reduce:"rp_1", sharded: true }});
```

This command works fine in sharding also, but when I enter:

```
db.test_collection.mapReduce(mapMaster , reduce , {out: {reduce:"rp_1", sharded: true }});
```

it gives duplicate key error insert fail.... something like this.
Error code 11000....

Can anyone tell me why this problem is occurring in sharding only?
What I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Please give us the full error message. Are you pulling input from a sharded collection, outputting to a sharded collection, or both? Also, if you could format your reduce code so it's readable it will be helpful if the problem ends up living there.

Comment: If `rp_1` has a document with the a specific `_id` in it after the first map reduce is run. The second map reduce would fail if a document with the same `_id` is generated during the second map reduce.

Comment: Cureently I am inserting data through MapReduce.                                                                 db.test_collection.mapReduce(mapMaster , reduce , {out: {reduce:"rp_1", sharded: true }}); ,
 sharded : true}});
2015-01-29T20:31:45.507+0000 map reduce failed:{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "MR post processing failed: { result: \"rp_1\", chunkS
izes: [], errmsg: \"exception: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 dupli
cate key error index: MyDB.rp_1.$_id_  dup key: { : \"ID0003\" }\", c
ode: 11000, ok: 0.0 }"
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1224

Comment: Yes, It has the same _id(CODE) because I want to club both map data through CODE field only. Is there any way to implement this ?